# PowerShell: Passed Parameters not in Format String

Tags: powershell

I'm a PowerShell newbie and I've got stuck on something very simple.  I am trying to create a variable that use placeholders (`{0}{1}...`) using string format (`-f`).  The place holder variables are passed as parameters to the function that builds/formats the string.  Unfortunately, the place holders remain blank.

Here's my code:

```
function SendName(){
  BuildReport $MyInvocation.MyCommand, 1, 2
}

Function BuildReport($functionName, $param1, $param2){    
    $report="You are in {0}. Parameter expected is {1}. Actual parameter is {2}" -f $functionName, $param1, $param2
    write-host $report
}

SendName
```

The output I get is:

> You are in System.Object[]. Parameter expected is . Actual parameter is

Answer (score 2):

You have to omit the comma (`,`) where you invoke the `BuildReport` method:

```
BuildReport $MyInvocation.MyCommand 1 2
```

Otherwise you will pass an *array* as the first parameter and `$param1` and `$param2` won't get populated.

The Output will be:

```
You are in SendName. Parameter expected is 1. Actual parameter is 
2
```

Comment: Thank you Martin that's brilliant.  SB

Comment: To explain further: PowerShell parameters are passed to functions using spaces, not commas. Commas are valid syntactically but wrong semantically - as Martin pointed out, using commas passes an array (which is not what you intended).

Comment: @user9850983 If an answer was helpful, it's best practice to up vote it or accept it.